# Weakest curvature assumption for existence of harmonic coordinates

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature

Let (M, g) be a Riemannian manifold. What are the weakest curvature bounds for which one can construct harmonic coordinates on M (or at balls contained in M)? Does anybody maybe know if it is possible to get such coordinates when one just assumes a L^{n/2} bound on the negative part of the Ricci curvature?

Comment: Looks like a question suitable for mathoverflow, not for MSE.